# randomly delete up to 3 elements per row

Tags: r

I would like to randomly delete up to three elements per row of a data set containing five columns.  Below is `R` code I thought would do it, but it allows up to all five elements in a row to be deleted.  This seems basic, but I cannot find the error.  Thank you for any advice.

```
set.seed(1234)

  # create matrix to contain flags identifying elements to be deleted
  delete.these <- matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=5)

  for(i in 1:nrow(delete.these)) {

      # for each row randomly select the order of the columns 
      # to be tested for deletion 
      rcols <- sample(5, 5, replace = FALSE)

      for(j in 1:ncol(delete.these)) {

           # select a random draw
           delete.it <- runif(1,0,1)

           # if random draw is below specified threshold and fewer than three
           # elements have already been deleted from the row then delete element
           if((delete.it <= 0.7) & sum(delete.these[i,1:5] <= 2)) { delete.these[i,rcols[j]] = 1}
           if((delete.it >  0.7) | sum(delete.these[i,1:5] >= 3)) { delete.these[i,rcols[j]] = 0}

      }
  }

  delete.these
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `runif()` try drawing the indices directly

```
delete.these <- matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=5)
for (i in 1:NROW(delete.these)){
   delete.these[i,sample.int(5,sample.int(4,1)-1)] <- 1
}
delete.these
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    1    0    1    1
 [4,]    0    1    1    0    1
 [5,]    1    0    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    1
 [9,]    0    1    1    0    0
[10,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

By the way your code doesn't work because of a misplaced paren.

```
 sum(delete.these[i,1:5] <= 2)
```

should be instead

```
 sum(delete.these[i,1:5]) <= 2
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want three elements deleted per row.  I would like a maximum of three elements deleted per row.

Comment: Oops.  Ok, updated the code to select UP TO 3.  Still no need for `runif()`

Comment: Thank you!  It's been a long day.

Comment: I also need to delete the second `if` statement in my original post.  It overwrites the output of the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier (and much faster) to delete with a two column-matrix as an argument to `[<-`. You did not propose a test case but I will:

```
 dfrm <- data.frame(a1=rnorm(20), a2=rnorm(20),a3=rnorm(20),
                     a4=rnorm(20),a5=rnorm(20))
 dfrm[ matrix( c( rep(1:20,each=3),
                  replicate(20,  {sample(5, 3)} ) ), ncol=2) ] <- NA

> dfrm
           a1          a2            a3          a4         a5
1          NA  0.70871541            NA          NA -0.6922827
2   1.9846227  1.70592512            NA          NA         NA
3   0.2684487          NA  0.0008968694          NA         NA
4          NA          NA  0.5546355410  0.07399188         NA
5          NA  0.82324761 -0.0410918599          NA         NA
6          NA          NA -1.0715205164          NA -0.1683819
7   0.0933059          NA            NA          NA  1.3129301
8          NA  0.79382695  0.1877369725          NA         NA
9   0.3124101          NA            NA -1.22087347         NA
10 -0.1657043          NA            NA  1.36626832         NA
11         NA -0.06095247 -0.9622792102          NA         NA
12         NA -1.29243386 -1.2133819819          NA         NA
13 -0.0886702          NA            NA  0.37495775         NA
14  1.0812527 -1.54215156            NA          NA         NA
15         NA -0.24765627            NA  0.81374405         NA
16         NA  0.21307051            NA          NA -0.6825013
17 -0.4129100          NA            NA          NA -0.9844177
18         NA  1.95881167  0.7977172969          NA         NA
19         NA          NA  0.0953287645          NA  1.7067591
20         NA          NA -0.1057690912  0.73408897         NA
```

This is assuming that by "delete" you meant set to missing. If the intent were something else you will need to supply a test case and clarify.

This (nested sampling strategy will provide a variable number of rows in the indexing matrix per row of the target matrix:

```
idx <- sapply(1:20, function(x) {n<- sample(1:5, sample(1:3,1)) 
                       matrix( c(rep(x,length(n)), n), ncol=2) }) # list
idx <- do.call(rbind, idx) # now a 2 col matrix

dfrm[ idx] <- NA

>     idx <- sapply(1:20, function(x) {n<- sample(1:5, sample(1:3,1)) 
+                            matrix( c(rep(x,length(n)), n), ncol=2) }) # list
>     idx <- do.call(rbind, idx) # now a 2 col matrix
> 
>     dfrm[ idx] <- NA
> 
> dfrm
             a1         a2         a3          a4         a5
1  -0.048776740         NA  1.1879195 -0.23142932 -3.6185891
2            NA  0.4613289 -0.4532400 -0.85891682 -2.2034714
3            NA         NA  1.1191833  1.12545821         NA
4   0.646399767 -0.7126735  2.9474470  0.36358070         NA
5  -0.630929314  1.3770828         NA          NA  1.3987857
6            NA         NA         NA  1.06680025  0.4445383
7   0.484728630         NA  0.7382064          NA  0.9838159
8  -1.558031074  1.1630888         NA          NA         NA
9  -0.968887379 -0.7330051         NA  0.04621124 -0.9785049
10  0.935436533         NA         NA -1.07365274         NA
11           NA  0.2529093         NA -1.38643245 -1.3389529
12           NA -0.2639166 -0.2301257          NA         NA
13  2.026646586 -0.2452684         NA -0.30346521         NA
14  0.522717033         NA         NA  1.25870278         NA
15           NA         NA -0.9934046 -0.89009964 -0.8403772
16           NA         NA  0.0987765 -0.98608109  1.4646301
17           NA  0.7693064 -0.9326388 -0.16240266         NA
18 -0.005393965         NA         NA          NA -0.8111057
19           NA  1.6241122 -1.1376916  0.15812435         NA
20           NA         NA         NA  0.71059666  0.5170046
```

Comment: In your example every row has three deleted elements.  I would like a maximum of three deleted elements per row.  A row can have 0, 1, 2 or 3 elements deleted.